# How do I create an executable in python using Opencv on OsX ?

Tags: python, macos, opencv

Here is my code :
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I used py2app to make an executable,
and when I run the code, an error window opens
["name of file error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yej9w.png)

How do I fix this code in order to make a working executable ?

Comment: Cam Error does that mean your executable can't access the camera?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I think the problem comes from OpenCV. I actually tried to use OpenCV for another code, but it's a bit more complex and the issue is similar to the one above.

Comment: Does the code above work as a python script instead of an executable?

Comment: Yeah, it also works as a script

Comment: So it only doesn't work when it's an executable? Might come down to some permissions of what app is allowed to use the camera, maybe look into that.